# Append text to a td cell by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append some text to the *Name* column by jquery, 
I tried this but no luck:

```
$(".ms-listviewtable").closest("tr").next().find(".ms-vb2:first").append("<p>test</p>");
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w0Lrvo5y/1/)

Comment: to which td you want to append?

Comment: After the name (Robert)

Comment: The sample is at the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".ms-listviewtable").find(".ms-vb2:first").append("<p>test</p>");
```

See the fiddle

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w0Lrvo5y/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use This it will work there

```
$(".ms-listviewtable tr:first td").eq(1).append("<p>test</p>");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/w0Lrvo5y/2/)

Answer (score 0):

.closest() starts looking for the element traversing the DOM upwards, and you want to go downwards, inside your table.

Use `.find()` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/w0Lrvo5y/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".ms-listviewtable").find("tr:first").find(".ms-vb2:eq(1)").append("<p>test</p>");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/w0Lrvo5y/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)").hide();
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w0Lrvo5y/9/

Basically just reach the parent element of the element you want to change and then access it using nth-child jQuery selector.

If you want to select which parent element to access you can use jQuery selector for that too.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to target the td containing 'Name' you could write

```
$(".ms-listviewtable .ms-vb2").first().append("<p>test</p>");
```

This will target the first td with the class *.ms-vb2* within *.ms-listviewtable*

Does this answer your question?